# What do shiny ovals mean on Magic the Gathering cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have just bought a set of Oath of the Gatewatch cards, and a few of them have a small shiny oval on the bottom center, like [Corrupted Crossroads](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Corrupted%20Crossroads).

What does this mean?

Comment: It is similar to the Eye of Anubis that the yugioh cards have.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of the [Magic 2015 redesign](http://www.gatheringmagic.com/adam-styborski-01062014-new-card-frame-coming-in-magic-2015/), rare and mythic rare cards will have a spot at the bottom of the card frame containing a small holofoil stamp. This has two effects:

1. It makes it harder to produce counterfeit versions, so it's a sign of authenticity.
2. It makes the card seem more special. Look, shiny!

Comment: Some promo cards (like the FNM promos) also have it regardless of rarity.

Comment: Can you explain what FNM is?

Comment: [Friday Night Magic](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiq8JG_yd7KAhXMSyYKHa67Dd4QFggkMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmagic.wizards.com%2Fen%2Fevents%2Fevent-types%2Ffriday-night-magic&usg=AFQjCNEAJm8VRZWBO-2_V9fwRsRHfAwdiA&sig2=6JdEKm69WEEvbpnQDCuBiA&bvm=bv.113370389,d.cWw)